# Where to place .js files when using AngularJS ui.router?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, uiview

Here I have my Angular module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide){
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
   $stateProvider.state('aaa', {
        url: '/aaa',
        views: {
            'menu-content': {
                templateUrl: 'resources/views/aaa.jsp',
                controller: 'AaaController',
                controllerAs : "aaaCtrl"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have main page, its url is '/'. I added app_script.js in its header:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/app_scripts.js"/>"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="app">
      <div ui-view="menu-content"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

app_script.js content:

```
$(function(){
   $('#myModalSubmit').click(function() { //component #myModalSubmit exists in template resources/views/aaa.jsp
      alert('click');
   });
});
```

The problem is that when I load the template in `ui-view` component, the jquery script doesn't work. It only works after I reload the page. I think it doesn't work from the first, because there are no component with id 'myModalSubmit' in the main page '/'. It only appears when `ui-view` is loaded.

So my question is, where should I include my app_script.js file if I want it to execute on template `resources/views/aaa.jsp` which is loaded in `ui-view`? Should i include it directly in a template? I tried this, but it didn't work too.

Comment: did you try `<script src="resources/js/app_scripts.js"></script>`?

Comment: What do you mean? Should I place it in a template file? I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: i mean have you tried `<script src="resources/js/app_scripts.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/app_scripts.js"/>"></script>`?

Comment: Tried just now, still works just after page reload.

Comment: yeah, it should

Comment: So what is wrong? Where do you guys include your .js files? In main page header or in each template? Why does my script not work?

Comment: something along the lines of `var testVar = require("resources/js/app_scripts.js")` in your file that uses the script

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, could you please be more specific? I'm not familiar with this function. Is this a jQuery function? How should I use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142061/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-polis).